# Convert From PHP and PDF

Tags: php, html, pdf, dompdf

I need to convert from Php(html Table) to Pdf. I have used the DOM PDf for the conversion. But i didn't get the proper view in pdf. please find the below images.

Pdf View

[image: PdfView]

HTML View

[image: Html View]

Code Below:

```
<html>
  <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
  </head>
<?php if(count($this->userDetails)>=1){ for($a=0;$a<count($this->userDetails);$a++){ $user = $this->userDetails[$a]; ?>
  <body>
    <div style="background-image: url(http://192.168.2.26/skins/schooladmin/images/id_bg.png); background-repeat: repeat; width:400px; height:220px;margin:10px 0px 0px 10px;float:left;position:relative;">
<table style="font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:14px; font-weight:bold; color:#fff; background-image:url(http://192.168.2.26/skins/schooladmin/images/id_white_bg.png); background-repeat:no-repeat;" width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5">
  <tr>
    <td style="background-image: url(http://192.168.2.26/skins/schooladmin/images/schoollogo.png); background-repeat:no-repeat; width:36px; height:61px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td colspan="2"><?php echo $this->schoolDetails['name'] ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php
    if($user){
    $user['userdetails']['name'] = $user['userdetails']['firstname'].$user['userdetails']['lastname'];
    $photoPath = BASE_PATH."/uploads/photos/student/".$user['userdetails']['photo'];
    if(!file_exists($photoPath)){
        $photoPath = BASE_PATH."/skins/schooladmin/images/id_photo.png";
    }
    }else{
        $photoPath = BASE_PATH."/skins/schooladmin/images/id_photo.png";
    }
?>
  <tr>
    <td style="background-image: url(<?php echo $photoPath; ?>); background-repeat:no-repeat; width:82px; height:82px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td colspan="2">
    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="3" cellpadding="3" style="font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; font-weight:bold; color:#fff;" >
    <?php if($this->templateDetails['template']){ 
        for($i=0;$i<1;$i++){
            for($j=0;$j<count($this->templateDetails['template_details']);$j++){
                if($this->templateDetails['template_details'][$j]['type'] == "text" && $this->templateDetails['template_details'][$j]['page'] == "front"){
    ?>
      <tr>
        <td width="38%"><?php echo $this->templateDetails['template_details'][$j]['label']; ?></td>
        <td width="62%"><?php echo @$user['userdetails'][$this->templateDetails['template_details'][$j]['field']]; ?></td>
      </tr>
    <?php } } } } ?>
    </table>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3" style="font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; font-weight:bold; color:#fff;"  align="center"><?php echo $this->schoolDetails['address'] ?>, <?php echo $this->schoolDetails['address2'] ?>, <?php echo $this->schoolDetails['city'] ?> - <?php echo $this->schoolDetails['zipcode'] ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3" style="font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; font-weight:bold; color:#fff;"  align="center">Ph: <?php echo $this->schoolDetails['contactno'] ?></td>
    </tr>
</table>
    </div>

    <div style="background-image: url(http://192.168.2.26/skins/schooladmin/images/id_bg.png); background-repeat: repeat; width:400px; height:220px;margin:10px 0px 0px 10px;float:left;position:relative;">
<table style="font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:14px; font-weight:bold; color:#fff; background-image:url(http://192.168.2.26/skins/schooladmin/images/id_white_bg.png); background-repeat:no-repeat;" width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5">
    <?php if($this->templateDetails['template']){ 
        for($i=0;$i<1;$i++){
            for($j=0;$j<count($this->templateDetails['template_details']);$j++){
                if($this->templateDetails['template_details'][$j]['type'] == "text" && $this->templateDetails['template_details'][$j]['page'] == "back"){
    ?>
      <tr>
        <td width="38%"><?php echo $this->templateDetails['template_details'][$j]['label']; ?></td>
        <td width="62%"><?php echo @$user['userdetails'][$this->templateDetails['template_details'][$j]['field']]; ?></td>
      </tr>
    <?php } } } } ?>
</table>
    </div>
    <?php } }  ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm not sure DOMPDF handles CSS or tables very well. Have you tried using another PDF library such as [TCPDF](http://www.tcpdf.org/), or [MPDF](http://www.smaizys.com/php/mpdf-html-to-pdf-introduction/)?

Comment: I had used TCPDF, it worked well.

Comment: TCPDF not support for me

Comment: For determining the quality of rendering it would help to see the HTML, not the PHP that generates the HTML. DOMPDF 0.6.0 (currently in beta) supports both tables and CSS (though there are currently a few known issues).

Comment: @PenguinCoder i have used mpdf, its working fine, thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: You could try to use one of HTML to PDF Rest Apis like http://www.convertapi.com

Comment: @Mr.T.K - why does TCPDF not work for you?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend not trying to massage your HTML so that it converts to PDF this way.  You'll expend far to much effort tweaking things that can change when you switch rendering engines or even printers.

You'll have an easier time if you create your PDFs natively using [FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/) or [TCPDF](http://www.tcpdf.org/).  For example (just to get you started):

```
<?php

require_once('/path/to/tcpdf.php');

// misc variables
$lightblue = array(100, 100, 250);
$darkblue = array(0, 0, 255);
$white = array(255, 255, 255);

// prepare new PDF document
$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);
$pdf->SetFont('helvetica', 'B', 20);

// add a page
$pdf->AddPage();

// set the coordinates of the gradient
$coords = array(0, 1, 1, 0);

// paint a linear gradient
$pdf->LinearGradient(20, 45, 105, 60, $lightblue, $darkblue, $coords);

// write text
$pdf->SetTextColorArray($white);
$pdf->Text(40, 50, 'hello');
$pdf->Text(40, 60, 'world');

// Close and output PDF document
$pdf->Output('tkexample.pdf', 'I');
```

Answer (score 0):

For geeting 100% same view, use php fpdf library.You can get all the supports, tutorials and download from [here](http://www.fpdf.org)